# How do I use my tsconfig file with ng-packagr?

Tags: ng-packagr

I'm packaging an Angular 5 library with ng-packagr and I need to use my existing tsconfig.json. I've read the docs here https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/override-tsconfig.md and it says I need to write a script (I was expecting an option in the config) and pass through the filepath to my tsconfig file.

I don't understand where I write this code? I guess this needs to be an NPM script? The documentation and example seems to be very minimal.

Help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a `build-package.ts` file with the contents (but require not import) then did:

`node build-package.ts`.

Comment: Could you explain how you solved it? I have the same question and I don't understand your answer. Could you show the contents of the build-package to see how you did the require? And how did you build your package before and after you've used a specific tsconfig?